# How can I make the black background of the div visible?

Tags: css, html, svg, background

How can I make the black background of the div visible?

```
<svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" width="300" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" />
    <circle cx="150" cy="100" r="80" fill="green" />
    <text x="150" y="125" font-size="60" text-anchor="middle" fill="white">SVG</text>
  </svg>
  <div style="background:black;color:white;margin-top:-50px;">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  </div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/rHlE2AdfkR81zVjE3oez?p=preview

Thanks.

Comment: According to me via Plunker seen on Chome it's quite visible through the link though a part of it is behind the SVG graphic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `relative position` to black div.

[**Link.**](http://plnkr.co/edit/AQNPyyuAjqsSuTwscuBM?p=preview)